# как pd.read_excel при загрузке запретить преобразовывать datetime?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, datetime

Загружаю данные по сотрудникам из турникетов (учёт рабочего времени) из .ods-файла.
Как таковых дат там нет, есть время входа и выхода каждый день в формате HH:MМ, и в последнем столбце суммарное время в часах:минутах:секундах типа такого 141:59:30;
При загрузке датасета:

```
df = pd.read_excel('#январь.ods', engine="odf").fillna(0)
```

возникает:

> ```
> ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 141:59:30
> ```

Номер столбца заранее не известен (кроме того что он последний)
Научите, как уговорить НЕ ПАРСИТЬ Дату/Время а сохранить в ячейках эти значения в виде строк? Я их потом обработаю сам.
[ссылка на файл данных](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j0EEraI-JbfXKoaliXi_LV85S3_nIAk5/view?usp=sharing)